# The best way to get embedded documents in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I has in MongoDB documents like this:

```
{
"user": ObjectID("4d71076b26ab7b032800009f")
"pages" : [
    {
        "name" : "Main",
        "content" : [
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("4d71076b26ab7b052800009f")
            },
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("4d61269b1deb5a3fce000004"),
                "link" : "http://example.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

You can see that the key "pages" is a array with other documents. Now I can query this document with the name of a page and I will get the full document with all pages and other information. I use in python directly pymongo to query the document but now I don't know what the best way is to get a page from the array pages. I think something like this:

```
def getPage(pageNameWhoINeed):
    for page in pages:
        if page['name'] == pageNameWhoINeed:
           return page
```

But is this the best way to get a singe page or general a embedded document? All tipps or code snippets are welcome.

Thanks!
Jarus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. In mongodb you can't load embedded document without parent. You can load parent document by some property of child document.

```
pages.find({"pages.name", "Main"}); //should load all document that contains pages  collection and at least one item in embedded collection with name 'Main'.
```

Than you need to iterate through all embedded documents an find page that you need.

If you often need to load embedded document, mb you need to redesign your database(move pages to the root collection, but it seems to me that all okay with your schema).

Comment: Per http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142 , hopefully this feature will be baked into MongoDB sometime, but is currently unscheduled. For now filtering manually is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Retrieving a Subset of Fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) on the mongodb website.

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't need the first or the last object from the array. I want a object with a special value in one of its keys. And this I couldn't build so far with the "$slice" operator. Should I understand something wrong than please correct me.

Comment: You can retrieve partial sub-objects via Dot Notation.